# Haskell function arguments (could not match type error)

Tags: haskell, tree

I am working with a tree structure and I have the following lines of code but I don't understand what causes the trouble. My reshapeTree function takes an AST and a Mapping as arguments and returns an AST. I really don't know what causes this error and would be grateful if you could help.Thank you

I get the following error and my code is below:

```
    test1.hs:55:35: error:
        * Couldn't match type [Char]' withAST'
          Expected type: [(String, AST, String)]
            Actual type: Mapping
        * In the second argument of reshapeTree', namelymapping'
          In the expression: reshapeTree tree mapping
          In an equation for `newTree': newTree = reshapeTree tree mapping
       |
    55 |  where newTree = reshapeTree tree mapping
       |                                   ^^^^^^^
```

`type Mapping = [(String, String, String)]
data AST = EmptyAST | ASTNode String AST AST deriving (Show, Read)

reshapeTree (EmptyAST) (_) = EmptyAST
reshapeTree (ASTNode val l r) [] = (ASTNode val l r)
reshapeTree (ASTNode val l r) [(v1,v2,v3)]
 |val == v1 = (ASTNode v3 v2 EmptyAST)
 |otherwise = (ASTNode val (reshapeTree l [(v1,v2,v3)]) (reshapeTree r [(v1,v2,v3)]))
reshapeTree (ASTNode val l r) ((v1,v2,v3):xs)
 |val == v1 = (ASTNode v3 v2 EmptyAST) 
 |otherwise = reshapeTree (ASTNode val (reshapeTree l ((v1,v2,v3):xs)) (reshapeTree r ((v1,v2,v3):xs))) xs


evalTree (ASTNode val l r)
 |val == "plus" = show (read (evalTree l) + read (evalTree r) )
 |val == "times" = show (read (evalTree l) * read (evalTree r) )
 |val == "cat" =  (evalTree l) ++ (evalTree r) 
 |val == "negate" = show ((-1) * read (evalTree l))
 |val == "len" =  show (length(evalTree l))
 |val == "str" = evalTree l 
 |val == "num" = evalTree r
 |otherwise = val

evaluateAST (tree,mapping)
 |mapping == [] = (tree,evalTree tree)
 |otherwise = (tree, evalTree newTree)
 where newTree = reshapeTree tree mapping`

Comment: I would strongly advise to include type signatures for all your top-level functions. If you did, then you would have seen at an earlier stage the real source of this error - that GHC infers the type of `reshapeTree` to be `AST -> [(String, AST, String)] -> AST` - when it seems you intended `AST -> Mapping -> AST`.

Comment: further, the reason GHC infers that type is this line from `reshapeTree`: `|val == v1 = (ASTNode v3 v2 EmptyAST)`. You are using `v2` as the second parameter to the `ASTNode` constructor, which according to your definition of `AST` must itself be an `AST`

Comment: Oh my! Thank you so much Robin! I was about to go crazy trying to figure out what is wrong. Your second comment fixed it!